# problem when concurrency set to 1 in stackstorm orquesta workflow with items model

Tags: concurrency

**Environment**:

stackstorm 3.8, python 3.8.10, multi docker instance deployment

**Problem**:

In orquesta workflow **with items**  definition, I want to apply the action to be applied to each item sequentially, so I set the concurrency to 1.

```
  parent_task:
    with:
      items: mw_id in <% ctx(mw_ids) %>
      concurrency: 1
    action: my_pack.my_action
    input:
      target_type: "node"
      trace_id: <% ctx().st2.action_execution_id %>
```

The problem is, if the action on one of the items (not the last one) fails, the action containing the **with items** definition fails abruptly and the remaining items after the failed item won't be processed.

The expected result is, all items are processed and the containing task succeeds only when all items are successfully processed, otherwise the containing task fails.

If the concurrency is not explicitly set, or is set to 2 or more, the result is as expected, all items are processed.